# AngularJS data binding with scope functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm new in Angular (i use 1.6)
I'm facing with data binding for the first time and I can load and refresh my data on a page simply by calling the web service every 3 seconds.

But I can't figure out how to tell to angular to call also the scope functions.
When the page load for the first time I load fake data and for every row I get a call to my scope functions job.rowColor and job.rowIcon that return CSS classes based on row status.

But when the interval expires and I load fresh data from server i see my new data load on page but without CSS classes computed from my scope function.
Why? 
Am I miss something?

This is my html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="JobController as job">

    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                            <th scope="col">User</th>
                            <th scope="col">Report</th>
                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                            <th scope="col">Files</th>
                            <th scope="col">Output</th>
                            <th scope="col">Start</th>
                            <th scope="col">End</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="row in job.data track by $index" class="table-{{job.rowColor($index)}}">
                            <th scope="row"><span class="oi oi-{{job.rowIcon($index)}}"></span> </th>
                            <th>{{row.Email}}</th>
                            <td>{{row.Type}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.Mode}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.TotalItems}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.Output}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.StartTime}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.EndTime}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

this is my controller:

```
.controller('JobController',function($scope,$http,$interval){
    var queue = this;
    queue.loadJobs=function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:55006/jobs-list/20/null/null').
        then(function(response) {
            queue.data = response.data;           
        });
    };

    $interval(function(){ queue.loadJobs(); }, 3000);
    queue.data=[
        {Status:'running',Email:'mmassari@mail.sm',Type:'Report1',Mode:'Multipage PDF',TotalItems:23,Output:'E-Mail',StartTime:'12:05',EndTime:'--:--'},
        {Status:'ok',Email:'mbaratti@mail.it',Type:'Report3',Mode:'Zipped PDF',TotalItems:39,Output:'E-Mail',StartTime:'12:05',EndTime:'10:30:15'},
        {Status:'error',Email:'acanducci@mail.it',Type:'Report3',Mode:'Multipage PDF',TotalItems:120,Output:'E-Mail',StartTime:'12:05',EndTime:'10:15:55'},
        {Status:'okerror',Email:'mmassari@mail.sm',Type:'Report5',Mode:'Zipped PDF',TotalItems:23,Output:'E-Mail',StartTime:'12:05',EndTime:'09:26:00'},
        {Status:'wait',Email:'eemo@mail.it',Type:'Report1',Mode:'Single PDF',TotalItems:1,Output:'Download',StartTime:'--:--',EndTime:'--:--'},
    ];
    queue.rowColor = function(index){
        switch(queue.data[index].status){
            case 'running': return 'primary';
            case 'wait': return 'secondary';
            case 'error': return 'danger';
            case 'okerror': return 'warning';
            case 'ok': return 'success';
        }
    }
    queue.rowIcon = function(index){
        switch(queue.data[index].status){
            case 'running': return 'play-circle';
            case 'wait': return 'media-pause';
            case 'error': return 'x';
            case 'okerror': return 'warning';
            case 'ok': return 'check';
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent long time to find out what is this code issue because I thought probably it is a bug in ng-repeat. But finally I found out your issue is misspelling the `status` (it is Capitalized in the data).

```
switch(queue.data[index].status){
```

must change to

```
switch(queue.data[index].Status){
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/arashsoft/2k3pojpv/2/

Comment: OMG! Thank you it works now, i have look at the code hundreds times and i just can't see this bug. In the fake data status is capitalized...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the index I suggest you always pass in the actual object.

View

```
class="table-{{job.rowColor(row)}}"
```

Controller

```
queue.rowColor = function(row){
        switch(row.status){
        .....
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it's better passing the row object but still doesn't solve my problem...